# Building Excel pivot tables programmatically

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I've written a script that builds excel reports. These reports may include pivot tables. To refresh a pivot table on load, I added `refreshOnLoad="1"` parameter to `pivotCacheDefinition1.xml` file. It works good with only one minor thing that I do not like - when I open a report, excel asks me "do you want to replace the contents of the destination cells"? I press "ok" and it refreshes pivot tables. I do not like this pop-up window with this question, and I think it's obvious that if `refreshOnLoad="1"` is specified then contents should always be refreshed. So, my question is how to suppress this window from popping up?

**EDIT**

According to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cf9c62b6-944c-4359-9de0-9e60f47ee9da/changing-source-data-of-pivot-table?forum=excel) thread:

> Whenever Excel will find that the update of it will replace the content of any existing cell,it will warn you.It is important feature.

So, does it mean that Excel will always warn, when it sees that pivot table contents should be refreshed?

**EDIT**

It seems like my problem is similar to [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=137490) one. However, I'm not using VB macros, I'm building my reports with some other programming language (which programmatically unzips xlsx file and deals with all those xml files inside).

**EDIT**

Well, I tried both `Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`, but none of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem, so these are more suggestions than answers.

I think the commands you are trying are occurring too late - Excel needs to know "not to alert before overwriting" before it tries to refresh. If it refreshes on open, then you set the property, you have the wrong sequence of events.

Try:

1. Do NOT put `refreshOnLoad="1"` in your file.
2. Add the VBA routine `Workbook_Open()` to the workbook.
3. In the VBA routine, set the property `Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False`, then invoke the method `PivotTable.Refresh`.

This should resolve any "sequence of events" problems.

Comment: I only wish, I could use refreshOnLoad=1 and still resolve "sequence of events". I just do not like the idea to rely heavily on VBA routines